# What would be iterative and efficient way to find all adjacent values that are connected in python matrix?

Tags: python, algorithm

recursive solution for large matrix creates stack overflow error

trying to identify island of same numbers in large matrix

e.g. following input matrix has  two islands of number 1, one island of each number 2 and 3

```
a =[
    [0,1,0,0,0,2,2,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,2,2,0],
    [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,3,3,0],
    [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
]
```

output

```
values for island 1 : [1,1,1,1,1,1]
values for island 2 : [1,1]
values for island 3 : [2,2,2,2]
values for island 4 : [3,3,3]
```

Comment: you could create a simple algorithm parsing a matrix in a sparse format (like from scipy.sparse)

Comment: check here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-number-of-islands/